# Parse xls/xlsx/xlsm in Node.js

Tags: excel, node.js, xls, xlsx, xlsm

Running in Node.js, I need to be able to parse cell *value's* from Excel .xls,.xlsx, and .xlsm.

Are there solutions available? I doubt there's a single module out there that will do the trick, so perhaps there is a way to internally convert two of the formats into the third and have a single format parser?

Has anyone else encountered this problem? If so, what kind of solution did you come up with?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Nirk I have both those up and working. *xlsm* is where I run into trouble

Comment: @gone What do you use for xls?

Answer (score 7):

The package https://npmjs.org/package/excel-parser works for XLS & XLSX

Comment: why vote downs? Anything wrong with npm module? I was thinking of using it.

Comment: how to install python in node.js application?

Answer (score 2):

The node module named 'xlsx' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) claims to parse *.xlsm files. I've used it with *.xls and *.xlsx files successfully. I don't see any reference to having to have Python installed, although I do have it installed so I can't be sure if it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that does not require python to be installed is [node-xlsx](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `excel-parser` or `xlsx` from `npm`.
more information [npm xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)